# how to make lg ultra fine monitor to work with windows?

Tags: lenovo-laptop, thunderbolt, lg-monitor

Recently purchased LG ultra fine monitor [LG ultra fine monitor](https://www.apple.com/shop/product/HMUA2VC/A/lg-ultrafine-4k-display?fnode=91ca2d422828c2b4c415d43c56dfe980eead65de282e3c5fde5a125ebf2d49d83dabe23ba83b06169ed89982be099a471584e1399b163441a2c37f04b1d225753d1917df848343e087519b6d34381f85b92177803ee109bccda442a546ab8ab3)

Wanted to make it work with my existing windows laptop which has type-c connector. When connected It identifies the monitor, but the monitor is just blank.

Only resource I found was from [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/apple/comments/5fan7e/lg_ultrafine_4k_compatible_with_windows_10_on_a_pc/) which has no solution.

How would I make it work with my existing laptop ? It would be annoying to have multiple monitors for each laptop :(

Laptop I am using for connection is : [Lenovo think pad A275](https://www.lenovo.com/us/en/laptops/thinkpad/thinkpad-a-series/ThinkPad-A275/p/22TP2TA2750). It has `Usb type C` port but it is not thunderbolt.

Comment: Not seeing why this is tagged macOS

Comment: As the monitor as no problems with macOS, I can remove the tag

Comment: Any one tried with external, trying to using this monitor with external GPU to connect to laptops which have no thunderbolt support ?

Comment: Try another cable.

Comment: This monitor has only type - c ports , i have tried all the cables

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This particular monitor totally lacks Windows support. It is by design made only for
the Mac.

You might make it work in a limited manner by connecting it via a
Thunderbolt 3 port.
If your computer only has USB-C, try a USB-C to Thunderbolt 3 adapter or hub.
Even in case of success, according to all reports it will never work on Windows
as well or as easily as on the Mac.